# Microservice Communication using reactive programming

Tags: apache-kafka, microservices, reactive-programming, micronaut

I have two microservices(A and B).

Service B receives HTTP requests from the UI. Based on some conditions service B requires data from a DB which only service A has access to. So I would need some communication mechanism between service B and A. So service B would internally call service A, retrieve some fields from the response from service A and eventually send the final response to the client.

I'm used to spring boot framework and AWS cloud resources. I'm new to reactive programming. The services are built using micronaut framework and utilise reactive programming. Kafka is also used as a messaging system.

In Spring boot, I would use a rest api and use webclient to make async calls from service B to service A. But with a rest API, I'll have to handle security and authentication as well.

With reactive programming in micronaut and kafka available, is there a better way for these microservices to communicate?

Update 1:

If a message bus is used, in an event-driven way, service B can't receive the response from service A right? Unless service B notes the message ID and service A publishes a message back with the required data from it's DB and mentions the appropriate message ID for that data sent.

Comment: Found a good blog related to microservice communication. [link](https://blog.logrocket.com/methods-for-microservice-communication/).

Answer (score 2):

Micronaut can also use both HTTP and Kafka.

Service-to-service communication simply requires a network link. Message buses / brokers are completely optional, but offer a way to buffer events and/or handle downtime.

Reactive programming doesn't really change this. It doesn't change the security model, either. Kafka and REST clients can still use TLS, and have authz restrictions.

---

> DB which only service A has access to

You could use Debezium; pulling the data into a Kafka topic from the database (if supported), then build a local, queryable KTable within "service B", rather than needing "service A"'s API at all.